# Probability of getting exactly $\alpha$ "A" runs and $\beta$ "B" runs in a randomly drawn word

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$. Each "word" that we can form using exactly $a$ times the letter $"A"$ and $b$ times the letter $"B"$ is written onto a card. Next, one of these $\pmatrix{a + b \\ a}$ cards is drawn randomly (so each card has the same probability of being drawn). The word on this card is now examined for "runs", that is, for subwords of maximal length, consisting of only one type of letter.

(For example, the word

$$A B A A A B B A B B B A A B$$

consists of four $A$-runs and four $B$-runs, starts with an $A$-run at the very left, and ends with a $B$ run at the right.)

I now want to figure out the probability $p(a, b; \alpha, \beta)$ of drawing a word that consists of exactly $\alpha$ $A$-runs and $\beta$ $B$-runs, with $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{N}$.

I must admit that I don't really know how to get started. My thought was to deal with the trivial cases first, and then maybe get the probability of the other ones by "crossing out" letter after letter until we recursively end up with a "trivial" case. But I haven't come very far yet.

I can see that $p(a, b; \alpha, \beta) = 0$ if $\alpha > a$ or $\beta > b$, because there can't be any runs of "zero length", so we need at least $\alpha$ letters to get $\alpha$ $A$ runs, and the same is true for $b$.

Also, for $\alpha = \beta = a = b = 1$, the probability is $1$. This may sound obvious, but if I recursively want to find out a formula, maybe it's helpful at some point.

If this exact question but under a different "disguise" (e.g. with coin flips instead of drawn words) has already been asked, then I would of course appreciate being linked to it; but even though the search function delivered several questions about "runs" or "streaks" in e.g. coin flip games, I couldn't find one that came close enough to my question to get me started.

Comment: Also $\Pr (|\alpha-\beta|\gt 1)=0$ for any $a,b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\alpha$ from 1 to $a$, the $A$s can be partitioned into $\alpha$ non-empty groups in $a-1\choose \alpha-1$ ways, while for $\beta$ from 1 to $b$, the $B$s can be partitioned into $\beta$ non-empty groups in $b-1\choose \beta-1$ ways.

To create a random permutation we alternate $A$ groups and $B$ groups. If $|\alpha-\beta|=1$, the number of ways to do it is ${a-1\choose \alpha-1}{b-1\choose \beta-1}$.  If $\alpha=\beta$, the number of ways is twice the product, i.e.,  $2{a-1\choose \alpha-1}{b-1\choose \beta-1}$.

Dividing by $a+b\choose a$ gives the probability.

This solution comes from Section 6.1 (page 63-64) of *Problems and Snapshots from the World of Probability* by Blom, Holst, and Sandell.